# dynamically adding edittext depending on the elements of json array

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch data from json array and display in edittext but i want to represent each element in seperate edittest,when the json array contains more than one element all the elements are single eddittext,how can i dynamicallly add edittext based on number of elements in the array

```
final String[] mList = assetName.split("\\|");
final String[] mListnumber = assetNumber.split("\\|");
for(i=0;i<mList.length;i++){
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View child=inflater.inflate(R.layout.childlayout,null);
    EditText title1=(EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.et_armoryname);
    EditText title2=(EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.et_armorynumber);
    //EditText title3 = (EditText)child.findViewById(R.id.et_qr);

    title1.setText(mList[i]);
    title2.setText(mListnumber[i]);

}
```

Comment: try this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136307/5860777

Comment: Use RecyclerView or ListView https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

dont create ui for editext use like this.

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int VISIBLE = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //for json data in spouse it is in arraylist otherwisse parse data and store in arrylist or any other variable.
                 iterator itr=al.iterator();  

             while(itr.hasNext()){  

        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setText(itr.next());
        editText.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }}

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Code to add `EditText` Dynamically into your parent Layout ,Pass Parent Layout Object in below method I have taken `LinearLayout`.

```
final String[] mList = assetName.split("\\|");
final String[] mListnumber = assetNumber.split("\\|");
```

make sure your `mList` Array and `mListnumber` Array length should be same other wise it may cause for ArrayIndexOutOfException.

```
private void addEditTextDynamically(LinearLayout mParentLayout, String[] myList) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) 
   {
     EditText myEditText = new EditText (mParentLayout.getContext()); //Context
     myEditText.setLayoutParams(new      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     myEditText.setId(i);
     myEditText.setTag(myList[i]);
     myEditText.setText(myList[i] + " number" + mListnumber [i]);
     myEditText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#785412"));
     mParentLayout.addView(myEditText);
    }
}
```